# What is the most elegant way to apply custom function to PySpark dataframe with multiple columns?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I need to create new fields based on three dataframe fields. This works but it seems inefficient:

```
def my_func(very_long_field_name_a, very_long_field_name_b, very_long_field_name_c):
  if very_long_field_name_a >= very_long_field_name_b and very_long_field_name_c <= very_long_field_name_b:
    return 'Y'
  elif very_long_field_name_a <= very_long_field_name_b and very_long_field_name_c >= very_long_field_name_b:
    return 'Y'
  else: 
    return 'N'

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
my_udf = F.udf(my_func)

df.withColumn('new_field', my_udf(df.very_long_field_name_a, df.very_long_field_name_b, df.very_long_field_name_c)).display()
```

Is it possible to just pass the dataframe like so? I tried but got an error:

```
def my_func(df):
  if df.very_long_field_name_a >= df.very_long_field_name_b and df.very_long_field_name_c <= df.very_long_field_name_b:
    return 'Y'
  df.elif very_long_field_name_a <= df.very_long_field_name_b and df.very_long_field_name_c >= df.very_long_field_name_b:
    return 'Y'
  else: 
    return 'N'

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
my_udf = F.udf(my_func)
df.withColumn('new_field', my_udf(df)).display()

Invalid argument, not a string or column:
```

The reason I want to shorten it is because I have create six new fields. It seems inefficient to copy and paste all the field names passed as arguments, so I'd like to know if there's something cleaner.